# Auth0 error logs export to Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights, auth0

We are trying to send our auth0 logs to Azure App Insights. We have used the extension available for Application Insights and it seems to be sending logs.

The questions is :

1. Where can I find these in the Application Insights?
2. Any specific table (log analytics) where this goes in?

I have tried almost all the LA tables and also searched on the App Insights but no help. The auth0 documentation on the extension doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: You can refer to a similar open issue on GitHub: [What log in Application Insights are they loaded to?](https://github.com/auth0-extensions/auth0-logs-to-provider/issues/97) or ask the same on [Auth0 Community](https://community.auth0.com/)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Thanks , I will follow-up on that community.

Comment: Seem like a complete ghosted response from Auth0

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps someone ,
After testing the POC , I have it figured out. The logs from auth0 will land in the 'customEvents ' table. Probably something that can be updated on the documentation for auth0 extensions.

Comment: How long does it take for the first logs to start showing up? Any idea?

Comment: @Phobis : a coule of hours and we were able to find them Created a table in our app insights dashboard to fetch these from LAW